# html/css : margin and padding values keep applying to entire div instead of just the text

Tags: css, html

I'm having an issue trying to center a piece of text inside a grey box, every time I move the text the entire grey box moves. I can't seem to figure this out. The problem is with the "show-collections-box" and the link to the collection text inside it. Thanks for any help.

Edit: So I made a `div id="show-collections-box"` which creates a grey box 228px by 50px. Inside the `div` I have a link, I wrpapped the link inside another `div` tag with `class="margin"`. When I apply the margin class, instead of only moving the link inside the `div class="margin"` down, the entire grey box, `div id="show-collections-box"`, plus the link is moved down 20px.

Here's a jsfiddle of it, you can see the 20px `margin-top` is pushing the entire grey box down 20px instead of just the word 'collections'.

http://jsfiddle.net/bfU3v/

HTML

```
      <div id="show-collections-box">
         <div class="margin"><a href="www.example.com">Collections</a></div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
    #show-collections-box {
        border-bottom: solid 1px #ececec;
        border-left: solid 1px #ececec;
        background: #faf9f9;
        width: 228px;
        height: 50px;

    }
    .margin {
           margin-top: 20px;
            }
```

Comment: If you don't give more details I don't see why a simple text-align: center wouldn't work. Also, you could try to set up a jsfiddle page.

Comment: Hi, text-align center won't work because I need the text "collections" to be centered up and down inside the height=50px grey div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain I know exactly what you're specific problem could be so this answer is based only on the limited information posted so far.

> ...every time I move the text the entire grey box moves.

This really sounds like you may be confused about how to apply margins & paddings to elements.

If you apply a `margin` to a `div`, that margin is located to the outside of the `div` thereby moving it around on the page.  The margin is **not** applied to the contents of the `div`.

If you apply `padding` to a `div`, that padding is located just inside the boundaries of the `div` thereby pushing its contents away from the `div`'s boundaries.  The padding is **not** applied to the contents of the `div`.

> The problem is with the "show-collections-box" and the link to the
>   collection text inside it.

You have not explained what the problem is.  Once you provide a more detailed explanation of exactly what you'd like to achieve, I'll edit this answer accordingly.

**EDIT:**

I believe there is probably a better way to achieve your goal but to answer your specific question, all I did was remove the inner `div` entirely and add the 20 pixels as top padding to the outer `div`.  (It should be noted that padding will *add* to the size of the `div`.  i.e., A 50 pixel high `div` with 20 pixels of top padding will end up being 70 pixels high)

http://jsfiddle.net/bfU3v/5/

**EDIT 2:**

If you only have one line of text that will not wrap **and** you know the height of the `div`, just add a `line-height` that equals the height of the `div`.  The text will always be vertically centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/bfU3v/7/

Comment: Hi I tried providing more information, please let me know if I need to explain something else. Thanks again.

Comment: @trying_hal9000, I answered your specific question with an updated fiddle as well as an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` to the container.

If for some reason you need the container to not be `inline-block`, add a second interior wrap with `width: 100%;` and `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/bfU3v/3/

no need to use 2 divs for this.